# How can I show toast when all checkboxes in my recyclerview are unchecked?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

The closest I can get is to show `toast` after each `checkbox` is unchecked, but I want to show `toast` only after they have **all** been unchecked. In my `onBindViewHolder` I have:

```
    ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked==false) {
                Toast.makeText(context_type, "all unchecked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }
    });
```

**Here is my Activity, NewContact.java, code (after request in comment below):**

```
    public class NewContact extends AppCompatActivity  {

        //in this JSONArray, checkedContacts, we will be storing each checkedContact JSON Object
        //Then we're going to post it to our NewContact.php file
        JSONArray checkedContacts = new JSONArray();

        Button phoneContacts;
        CheckBox mcheckbox;

        //thse are the fields in the xml
        private EditText categoryname;
        private EditText namename;
        private EditText phonename;
        private EditText addressname;
        private EditText commentname;

        int public_or_private;

        // ArrayList called selectPhoneContacts that will contain SelectPhoneContact info
        ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts;

        ArrayList<String> allPhonesofContacts;
        ArrayList<String> allNamesofContacts;
        ArrayList<String> MatchingContactsAsArrayList;
        String phoneNoofUserCheck;
        public String phoneNumberofContact;
        String phoneNameofContact;

        //For the recycler view, containing the phone contacts
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter;

        int check_counter = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);

            PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter = new PopulistoContactsAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, NewContact.this);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //we are fetching details for the recyclerview - the name, numbers, matching contacts...
            LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
            loadContact.execute();

            //selectPhoneContacts is an empty array list that will hold our SelectPhoneContact info
            selectPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

            //cast an EditText for each of the field ids in activity_new_contactact.xml
            categoryname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
            namename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            phonename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
            addressname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
            commentname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewComment);

            phoneContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoneContacts);

            phoneContactsButton();
            checkboxnull();

            public_or_private = 1;

        }

        // Load data in background
        class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                //code here to get allPhonesofContacts
                allPhonesofContacts = gson.fromJson(json, type);

                //code here to get allNamesofContacts
                allNamesofContacts = gson.fromJson(jsonNames, type);
                System.out.println("NewContact: allNamesofContacts :" + allNamesofContacts);

                //code here to get MatchingContactsAsArrayList 
                MatchingContactsAsArrayList = gsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList.fromJson(jsonMatchingContactsAsArrayList, type1);
                System.out.println("SelectPhoneContactAdapter MatchingContactsAsArrayList :" + MatchingContactsAsArrayList);

                //for every value in the allPhonesofContacts array list, call it phoneNumberofContact
                for (int i = 0; i < allPhonesofContacts.size(); i++) {

                    phoneNumberofContact = allPhonesofContacts.get(i);
                    phoneNameofContact = allNamesofContacts.get(i);

                    SelectPhoneContact selectContact = new SelectPhoneContact();

                    //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
                    if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(phoneNumberofContact))

                    {   //add the selectContacts to the selectPhoneContacts array
                        // insert the contact at the beginning of the listview
                        selectPhoneContacts.add(0, selectContact);

                        //In SelectContact class, so getItemViewType will know which layout to show
                        selectContact.setType_row("1");


                    } else {
                        // insert it at the end (default)
                        selectPhoneContacts.add(selectContact);
                        selectContact.setType_row("2");


                    }

                    selectContact.setName(phoneNameofContact);
                    selectContact.setPhone(phoneNumberofContact);

                }

                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

                PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter = new PopulistoContactsAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, NewContact.this);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(NewContact.this)));

  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

        }

        //for the Public Contacts button
        private void phoneContactsButton() {

            phoneContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter = new PopulistoContactsAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, NewContact.this);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    // recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(NewContact.this)));

                    //loop through the matching contacts
                    int count = PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                        //for  contacts that are checked (they can only be matching contacts)...
                        //PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.get(i).isSelected=true;
                        PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.get(i).setSelected(true);


                        //we need to notify the recyclerview that changes may have been made
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }


            });

        }

        private void checkboxnull() {


            //adapter.setOnClickListener(new PopulistoContactsAdapter.OnClickListener() {
             PopulistoContactsAdapter adapter = new PopulistoContactsAdapter(selectPhoneContacts, NewContact.this);


                adapter.SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(new PopulistoContactsAdapter.OnCheckBoxClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onCheckBoxClick(boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked)
                        ++check_counter;
                    else
                        --check_counter;


                    if (check_counter <= 0)
                        Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, "all unchecked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }


            });
        }


        //create a method in your first activity, (where the button color should change):
        public void changeColorInFirstActivity(){
           // Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoneContacts);
            phoneContacts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
}
```

**And my Adapter:**

```
public class PopulistoContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder > {
        private Context mContext;
        //make a List containing info about SelectPhoneContact objects
        public static List<SelectPhoneContact> theContactsList;
        Context context_type;
        private OnCheckBoxClickListener onCheckBoxClickListener;

        public class MatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
            public TextView title, phone;
            public CheckBox check;
            public Button invite;

            public MatchingContact(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
                //phone is cast to the id called no etc
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
                check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

            }

        }


        public class nonMatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
            public TextView title, phone;
            public CheckBox check;
            public Button invite;

            public nonMatchingContact(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
                //phone is cast to the id called no etc
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
                check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            //for each row in recyclerview, get the getType_row, set in NewContact.java
            return Integer.parseInt(theContactsList.get(position).getType_row());
        }

        public PopulistoContactsAdapter(List<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts, Context context) {
            //selectPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();


            theContactsList = selectPhoneContacts;


            this.mContext = context;
           // whichactivity = activity;
            context_type = context;


        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemView;

            //if getType_row is 1...
            if (viewType == 1)


            {


                Context context = parent.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint, parent, false);

                //itemView.setTag();
                return new MatchingContact(itemView);


            } else {


                Context context = parent.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint_non_matching, parent, false);


                return new nonMatchingContact(itemView);


            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            //bind the views into the ViewHolder
            //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
            //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:


            //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
            final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);


            //if the row is a matching contact
            if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)


            {
                //in the title textbox in the row, put the corresponding name etc...
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).getSelected());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);


                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                        Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();


                        //NEED THIS TO PRESERVE CHECKBOX STATE
                        //because it is onClick, getSelected will always be the same value
                        //false or true, it doesn't matter
                        if (theContactsList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                            Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } else {


                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                            Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " unclicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }
                });


                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                        onCheckBoxClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(isChecked);


                    }
                });


            }
            else {


                ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
                ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());


            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {


            return theContactsList.size();
        }


        public interface OnCheckBoxClickListener {
            void onCheckBoxClick(boolean ischecked);
        }


        public void SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(final OnCheckBoxClickListener onCheckBoxClickListener) {
            this.onCheckBoxClickListener = onCheckBoxClickListener;
        }


    }
```

Comment: define a variable in your calling Activity/Fragment and update it via interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with an `onClickListener`.

In my:

```
    ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });
```

I put:

```
                int count = 0;
                int size = theContactsList.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if (theContactsList.get(i).isSelected) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context_type, "All unchecked!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Why you choose to iterate all the checkboxes each time the user clicks one? You should save the count and update it with each click so you would save runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable to store the count of the selected checkboxes, and then on each check changed event update the count (add or substruct base on the checked value), and then if the count is 0 after you updated it, all the checkboxes are unchecked

something like that:

```
//if all the checkboxes are cheked by default
int count = theContactsList.size();
//if all the checkboxes are uncheked by defult
int count = 0;
```

and

```
((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if (!isChecked)
        {
              count--;
        }
        else
        {
              count++;
        }
        if(count<=0)
        {
            //all unchcked
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You mean something like `int count = theContactsList.size();` and `for (int i = 0; i < count; i--) { if ((isChecked(i)) == false` ? How should I put `i` in the `isChecked`, because right now it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Using Interface

Define this interface in your `Adapter`

```
private OnCheckBoxClickListener onCheckBoxClickListener;

public interface OnCheckBoxClickListener {
    void onCheckBoxClick(boolean ischecked);
}
```

Add

```
public void SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(final OnCheckBoxClickListener onCheckBoxClickListener) {
    this.onCheckBoxClickListener = onCheckBoxClickListener;
}
```

Update `onBindViewHolder`

```
((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        onCheckBoxClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(isChecked);

    }
});
```

in `Activity/Fragment`

```
int check_counter = 0;

    mAdapter.SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(new YourAdapterClass.OnCheckBoxClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckBoxClick(boolean ischecked) {
            if (ischecked)
                ++check_counter;
            else
                --check_counter;

            if (check_counter <= 0)
                Toast.makeText(context, "all unchecked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    });
```

Comment: Tx for code but the `Activity` part is giving me errors. So I wrapped it in a `private void checkboxchecker(){` and called `checkboxchecker();` in my `onCreate`, that crashed the app when the `activity` started. So then before the `adapter.SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(new YourAdapterClass` part I put `YourAdapterClass adapter = new YourAdapterClass etc..` Now activity starts but when I click `checkbox` I get `NullPointerException` on `onCheckBoxClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(isChecked);` Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your adapter class and calling activity i'll try to update your code

Comment: keep only one global object(adapter) of PopulistoContactsAdapter, use it everywhere in your Activity and use the same object(adapter) in checkboxnull() as well. Update and let me know if this works.

Comment: Now I get `NullPointerException` while `NewContact` tries to start. The error  is on `adapter.SetOnCheckBoxClickListener(new PopulistoContactsAdapter.OnCheckBoxClickListener() {`

Comment: Hey I managed to do it within my `onClickListener`, short and sweet. Thanks for your efforts. + 1